# Use Arrays when initializing another Array at specific position

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I have an integer array.
`int[] arr1 = new int[] {3, 4, 5};`. I want to insert this array when initializing another array. So that when
`int[] arr2 = new int[] {8, 7, arr1, 1, 0};`, arr2 will equal `{8, 7, 3, 4, 5, 1, 0}`.

Also, I do not know the length of `arr1`, so I can't do `int[] arr2 = new int[] {8, 7, arr1[0], arr1[1], arr1[2], 1, 0};`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: How to set an array with another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54576672/java-how-to-set-an-array-with-another-array)

Comment: Do you want a one-line solution or is it possible to answer in 2 or 3 lines?

Comment: @Milgo no, that doesn't solve my problem. It uses `ArrayUtils.addAll`. I need the array to be in a specific position in the second array.

Comment: there is no native way, write a for loop that iterates over the inner array and sets its values in the outer.

Comment: @0009laH I would of course prefer a one liner. But if it requires 2 or 3 lines, that's fine as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly as far as I'm aware something like that can't be done in a single operation. The best I was able to come up with is to create a `result` array. Then you copy to it first part of `arr2`, whole `arr1` and finally second part of `arr2`. In the end whole method would look like so:

```
private static int[] insertArrayAtPosition(int[] arr1, int[] arr2, int insertPos){
    int[] result = new int[arr1.length + arr2.length];
    System.arraycopy(arr2, 0, result, 0, insertPos);
    System.arraycopy(arr1, 0, result, insertPos, arr1.length);
    System.arraycopy(arr2, insertPos, result, insertPos + arr1.length, arr2.length - insertPos);
    return result;
}
```

And then you can call it like so:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] arr1 = new int[] {3, 4, 5};
    int[] arr2 = new int[] {8, 7, 1, 0};
    int[] result = insertArrayAtPosition(arr1, arr2, 2);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

Edit: Milgo's solution looks much better. However, mine allows to insert one array into another at specific position after they are already created. Which one to use depeds on the usecase.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ArrayUtils.addAll()` three times.

```
int[] arr1 = new int[] {3, 4, 5};
int[] arr2 = new int[arr1.length + 4];
ArrayUtils.addAll(arr2, new int[]{8, 7});
ArrayUtils.addAll(arr2, arr1);
ArrayUtils.addAll(arr2, new int[]{1, 0});
```

ArrayUtils is part of [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/).

Comment: The class `ArrayUtils` doesn't seem to exist. I am using Java 8 with no external libraries

Comment: It's part of Apache Commons.

Comment: Do it work when you explicitely import `org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils` in your code?

Comment: @0009laH No, you would have to download an external jar file first.

Answer (score 0):

This is not natively supported in java / there is no language feature that allows you to use a one liner.
You can of course write a loop that inserts the elements of the other array, you can also use list interfaces or Arrays#stream. The best way to do it should probably be to use lists, like this:

```java
List<Integer> arr1 = Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5);
List<Integer> arr2 = Arrays.asList(8, 7, 1, 0);
arr2.addAll(2, arr1);
```

Hope this helpes.

Edit: It is a one liner btw :)

Comment: `arr1` and `arr2` are `int[]`, not `List<Integer>`. Switching from one to another requires several lines of code

Comment: yes, im aware, but i said it could be better to use the List interface. Also, you can "convert" arrays to lists.

Comment: You can convert lists to arrays only when they have the same template (`List<Integer>` and `Integer[]`), but there is no one-line conversion for `List<Integer>` and `int[]`. It would require to cast each element from `Integer` to `int` or vice versa. Nonetheless, I agree it would be more adapted to work with `List<Integer>` in his case